# EDAC errors on server

Tags: memory

One of our servers has been generating a frequent error message that looks like this:

`kernel: EDAC MC1: 1 CE error on CPU#1Channel#0_DIMM#0 (channel:0 slot:0 page:0x0 offset:0x0 grain:8 syndrome:0x0)`

Unlike most questions that had similar error, my page and offset values are always 0x0. Is bad memory stick the issue in this case as well, or could this be an issue with other hardware instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how critical that server is you've essentially got two choices: swap the DIMM with another one and check whether the error moves accordingly or replace the DIMM ASAP.

Comment: We have swapped all memory sticks and keep getting the same exact error at the same location.

Comment: If it's not the RAM it's the system. It might be shot but it also just might be a BIOS bug.